# Pathmodel - Choosing the "correct" Estimator

Tags: multivariate-analysis, structural-equation-modeling, path-model

I am currently working on a mediation pathmodel with [lavaan](https://lavaan.ugent.be/) in R.
For the model I want to include 3 exogeneous variables that are sociodemographics.
One is metric (age) and the other are dummy coded (e.g. gender) and thus nominal scaled.

If I am not mistaken one of the assumptions for SEM or Pathmodels (especially if the ML Estimator is used) is,  that all variables are mutlivariate normal distributed. Which in case
of these nominal variables obviously can't be met.

I found a recommendation on one webseite to just use weighted least squares, if your SEM / Pathmodel includes categorical variables. For this reason I used `estimator = "wlsmv"` in my model.
Since the source for this was one website I am wondering if this approach is even correct? And if there would some standard literature to cite for the use of the estimators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an assumption that all of the variables are MV normal. It's an assumption that all endogenous variables are MV normal.

Weighted least squares is problematic, unless your sample is in the multiple thousands, and usually advised against.

If you have missing data, use the Yuan-Bentler T2*, which Lavaan calls MLR, and if you don't, then the Satorra-Bentler, which Lavaan calls MLM, is also appropriate (and equivalent).

Comment: So MV normal (or categorical endogenous vars) is not a problem for the Yuan Bentler T2* (MLR)? Sample Size is more like 500 then multiple thousands. I have a few missings (like 10-20 Samples) which could be also excluded in preprocessing PS: Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, categorical endogenous measures are not appropriate for S-B estimates, but yours (that you have mentioned) seem exogenous.