# SEM : WLSMV or WLS?

Tags: r, structural-equation-modeling, estimators, lavaan

I am conducting a SEM in `R` using `lavaan` and I am a bit lost regarding which estimator I should use. I have a model like the following :

[image]

The variables a,b,c,h are binary categorical and the rest are continuous non normal. I have encountered in some sources that categorical variables can cause problems when using the traditional Maximum Likelihood approach, e.g. Washington, S. P., Karlaftis, M. G., & Mannering, F. (2003). Statistical and econometric methods for transportation data analysis. Chapman and Hall/CRC :

> Nominal and ordinal scale variables also cause problems in SEMs
> resulting in biased estimates of X2 test statistics and estimated
> parameters and their standard errors. One approach, developed by
> Muthen (1984), consists of a continuous/categorical variable
> methodology (CVM) weighted least squares estimator and discrepancy
> function, which results in unbiased, con- sistent, and efficient
> parameter estimates when variables are measured on nominal and ordinal
> scales. However, this estimator requires large sample sizes (at least
> 500 to 1000 cases) and is difficult to estimate for overly complex
> models (Hoyle, 1995).

What is not clear to me is whether this is the case for any categorical variables within the model or this is just referring to the dependent/endogenous variables. If the case is any categorical variables, then it seems like the option of "WLSMV" available in `lavaan` should be the way to go.

If the case is that this refers only to dependent variables, `lavaan` offers the options of "WLS" for weighted least squares (also called ADF), which according to the references I encountered is an appropriate method that does not assume a normal distribution.

I also encountered this answer: [Pathmodel - Choosing the "correct" Estimator](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/505421/pathmodel-choosing-the-correct-estimator?rq=1) , suggesting the the Satorra-Bentler (MLM in `lavaan`) for non missing data when there are categorical exogenous variables. But is this also the case when the variables are latent indicators?

Any recommendations on which approach I should follow? My sample size is quite large (1700 observations). Any references would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting question. In my opinion, you should use WLSMV in lavaan. It is a robust variant of DWLS that correctly handles non-normal and discrete variables like those in your model. Regardless of this suggestion, I think your main question is whether the nature of the observed variables influence the choice of estimator, and the answer is yes. This is not a matter of the latent variables, but of the observed variables. Personally, I would like to recommend to you "Principles and Practice of Structural Equation Modeling by Rex B. Kline", especially Section "Robust WLS Estimation", Chapter 13.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I also confirmed from the lavaan google teams that for endogenous categorical data WLSMV is the best approach.